# List of some number ([1,1,1,1,1,1]) in haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Is it possible in Haskell to create list of some element by provided length?
In Python, I can write:

```
l = [1] * 10
```

How can I do it in Haskell?

Comment: Maybe you mean `replicate 10 1` ?

Comment: Thanks. How can I close question?

Comment: No need to close the question (although frankly, it _is_ a pretty poor one). You can accept your own answer.

Comment: I can't accept my answer :( "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: Check out [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/)! You can search for Haskell stuff by type signature. In your case, this signature would be either [`Int -> a -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Int%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) or [`a -> Int -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a%20-%3E%20Int%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D); `replicate` shows up in the first three results for each query.

Comment: I voted to close the question (because it was a duplicate) but also upvoted it, because I don't think it's a bad or off-topic question. Even though you *should* be able to delete the question (using the "delete" link at the bottom), please don't.  Even though it's been marked as a duplicate, it may help others who search for the answer to find the right solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Krzysztof Atłasik

```
replicate 10 1
```